# Pandas: Memory Error when merging dfs

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am merging to large data frames and am getting a memory error. I'm wondering if the error is because of poor coding or because the data frames are just to big. The data frames are dfy: 34.7 Mb and df: 2.2 Mb.

```
dfy = pd.read_csv('Thesis/CRSP/CampaignFin14/pacs14.txt', header=None, \
names=['cycle', '2', '3', 'cid', 'amount', 'date', 'catcode', 'type', 'di', 'feccandid'], \
usecols=['cycle', 'cid', 'amount', 'date', 'catcode', 'type', 'di', 'feccandid'])

dfy.head()



   cycle    cid       amount          date  catcode type    di  feccandid
0   2014    N00029285   1000    05/15/2014  E1600   24K     D   H8TX22107
1   2014    N00026722   5000    10/22/2013  G4600   24K     D   H4TX28046
2   2014    N00030676      4    03/26/2014  C2100   24Z     D   H0MO07113
3   2014    N00032088   1000    05/06/2014  F1100   24K     D   H0OH06189

df = pd.read_csv('Thesis/MapLight_data/mpl_data114.csv', header=None, names=\
    ['session', 'prefix', 'number', 'organization_id', 'name', 'disposition', 'catcode'], usecols=\
             ['session', 'prefix', 'number', 'disposition', 'catcode'])

df.head()

session prefix number disposition catcode
0   114     H   131     support     J6200
1   114     H   138     oppose      L1100
2   114     H   140     support       NaN
df_merge = pd.merge(dfy, df, on='catcode')
```

Comment: How big are the dfs?

Comment: 2.2 Mb and 34.7 Mb

Comment: Check for duplicates in `catcode` column.

Comment: I guess you should do it like this: `df_merge = dfy.merge(df, on='catcode')` or `df_merge = dfy.merge(df, on='catcode', how='left')`, assuming that `dfy` has more rows than `df`

Comment: Thanks for your comment MaxU. I applied your code and it is still running.  Could this potentially take a while? As you guessed, the larger file is dfy. I have updated the question accordingly.  Could this potentially take a while?

Comment: Could you post the output of `df.head()` for each?

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you for your comment. I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: Thanks for editing so far, can you also include the exact error message?

Comment: @Stefan: I set the code running again a while ago and it has not stopped yet. Will let you know when it does.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, it should not take _that_ long for such a DFs. Can you upload your DFs somewhere?

Comment: @MaxU: One of the problems could be that many of the rows in dfy will not match with rows in df. I have decided to approach the problem from a different angle. Should I delete the question? Here is [df](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/mpl_data114.csv.zip) 

and here is [dfy](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/pacs14.txt.zip)